# Execute the Code with Left Mouse Click useing pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want my code to run when I left click my mouse and use the position of my cursor as initial position. My code simply presses randomly between 1 and 5 and then presses tab and continue doing same thing in the loop. I have pre defined the cursor position for the program, but I want it to find the position of the cursor when I executed the code. I've searched for hours but couldn't find a solution. My code is below

```
import pyautogui
import random

j = int( input("How many boxes to fill : " ))

pyautogui.click(569, 464)
pyautogui.click(569, 464)
for i in range(j+1):
    j = random.randint(1,5)
    pyautogui.typewrite([str(j), '\t'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the purpose of `pyautogui` is to simulate a human being and their interaction with the program. Thus, you can't have the user trigger the program with a left click. You may have to provide a user input to start the program as follows:

```
>>> start = bool(input("Tell me should I start:: "))
Tell me should I start:: 1
>>> start
True
>>> if start:
...     #Your CODE
```

About the mouse position, you can find the answer in the PyAutoGUI [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html) itself about how you can get the mouse button position. You get it by using the `pyautogui.position()` routine

```
>>> pyautogui.size()
(1920, 1080)
>>> pyautogui.position()
(187, 567)
```

Comment: Thank your for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I did the trick by adding following codes. It is working not on left click but takes the cursor's position as initial position when I entered the number of boxes:

```
import pyautogui
import random

j = int( input("How many boxes to fill : " ))

x, y = pyautogui.position()

pyautogui.click(x,y)
pyautogui.click(x,y) #2 clicks are necessary for the task
for i in range(j+1):
    j = random.randint(1,5)
    pyautogui.typewrite([str(j), '\t'])
```